# MySQL get column names from a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to query the column names from a query, something like this:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM 
(SELECT `f1`, `f2`, `g1`, `g3` FROM `f` INNER JOIN `g` ON `g`.`Id` = `f`.`Id`)
```

And the result be

```
FIELD
f1
f2
g1
g3
```

Of course this query is wrong. But is there a way to do that?

Comment: You could create a view and then look at the columns in the view.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need, but if you need column names, you can "select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = yourtable"

Comment: @GordonLinoff, is user is asking for some kind of UNPIVOT thing?,i.e. columns into rows?

Comment: @AK47 . . . It seems pretty clear what the OP wants.  He has a query and he wants to know the column names, analogous to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` or `SHOW COLUMNS` but for a query instead of a database object.

Comment: @Marco , in which environment do you want to have this list ? It will be available as the keys of any row array in php ...

Comment: I use ajax (php/js) and I have a strong and well tested procedure for put data from a query in html... The point is that I have a group of queries with the same layout, but I don't know before hand what fields have this queries

Comment: I can program another procedure for this problem in ajax... But if there is a way to do that with a query in database I would dynamically built my tables and save me work! If there isn't... OK, let's work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need this?

If you want to use it in a procedure or similar, then you are already typed in the column names. If it is a dynamically generated query, use that method which generates the query to get the column names.

If you want to use them in your program, most languages provides functionality to get the resultsets column information.

`PDOStatement::getColumnMeta ( int $column )` in PHP with PDO
`OdbcDataReader.GetSchemaTable()` in .NET

**This solution is a hack!** (and not recommended and also not tested, just a suggestion!)

Create a temporary table based on the query (`SELECT .... INTO #temptable`) (possibly with a where clause which never evaulates to true (`WHERE 0=1`), then query that temp tables metadata from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Comment: Suppose that I have the same layout for a range of queries, and suppose that I don't know the fields that came from this queries, and suppose that I have a very good procedure to put data from a query that simplifies a lot things... That's why I want to do that

Comment: In this case rewrite your procedure to use temporary tables to store data while working with them or create views based on the queries then query those objects metadata. At the end of the procedure, you can drop those temporary objects.